# Dynamic length negative lookahead

Tags: r, regex

i want to build a regex to find occurences of the words `apple` and `orange` in a sentence. However,
i only want to extract them if they do not follow the words `no` or `without` plus a variable number of white spaces. Example

```
"apple orange" => apple, orange
"no apple orange" => orange
"apple apple without orange orange" => apple, apple, orange
```

So i achieved to create a regex that works for one space between the words:

```
str_extract_all("no apple orange", "(?<!(no|without)\\s)\\b((apple|orange))\\b")
```

However, if i change to no     apple orange ig get apple, orange. So my idea was to use this regex: `"(?<!(no|without)\\s*)\\b((apple|orange))\\b"` , however, negative lookaheads must be of a fixed length in R.

Any idea how to do this then?

Comment: Not  a problem if you assume a specific amount of whitespaces. Say, 0 to 1000: `\\b(?<!\\bno\\s{0,1000})(?<!\\bwithout\\s{0,1000})(apple|orange)\\b"`